# Поиск с ajax + django

Tags: ajax, django

Всем привет. Я хочу сделать поиск с помощью django и ajax. Когда я кликаю на кнопку, jQuery собирает данные и делать ajax запрос. Тут все хорошо. Но у view, когда я хочу вывести значение serch_by в консоль, там:

`None
qwer asdf zxvc` <- значения инпута

Я думаю проблема в этом, но неуверенный и не знаю как пофиксить

HTML:

```
<form id="searchform" {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="q" type="text" id="search">
  <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit"></button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function initSearchForm(){
    $('#searchsubmit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        q = $('#search').val();
        updateContentBySearch(q);
  });
}
function updateContentBySearch(q) {
    var data = {};
    data['search_by'] = q
    data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('#searchform [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search_products/",
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        success:
            $('.product_content').load(url, function() { ...
            }),
        });

    }
```

View:

```
def search_products(request):
     data = request.GET
     search_by = data.get('search_by')
     print(search_by) # The console is displayed first 'None' and at 
                      # the next line value of search_by
if search_by:
    q = Q()
    for tag in search_by.split():
        q |= Q(brand__brand_name__iexact=tag) | Q(model__iexact=tag)
    products = Product.objects.filter(q)

return render(request, 'main/product_content.html', {'products': product})
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы посылаете из ajax 'GET', но передаете как data: data, как post запрос. Попробуй те как ниже:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/search_products/?search_by="+q,
    type: 'GET',
    success:
        $('.product_content').load(url, function() { ...
        }),
    });

}
```